# Does Picasa retain picture quality and resolution upon upload and download?

Tags: picasa-web-albums

Photos of life events are getting uploaded instead of printed. There comes a time when you want to take those and actually print them. Does Picasa retain picture quality and resolution upon upload and download?

Facebook destroys photos by lowering their resolution and doesn't have a retrieval tool. I find Flickr quite slow.

Answer (score 4):

From [Picasa help site](http://picasa.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=166734):

> Picasa Web Albums can be used to backup your original files under the
>   following conditions:
>
> 1. The original file is a JPG.
> 2. The image can be no larger than 20MB and is restricted to 50
>      megapixels or less.
> 3. The image doesn't have any unsaved edits.
> 4. You upload the image at 'Original Size.'
>
> In all other cases Picasa will create and upload a new copy of your
>   image saved in the JPG format. Examples of when your original file
>   would not be uploaded include:
>
> - The original file is anything other than a JPG (TIF, PSD, any RAW
>     format, etc).
> - You have made edits such as I'm Feeling Lucky, Redeye, Crop, etc.
> - You select to upload at any resolution other than 'Original Size.'